# Show a string that contains two numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm studying SQL just recently and I have encountered a problem. I want to show the Address that contains only 2 digit numbers.

Example data below:

```
120 Annapolis St. Greenhills, San Juan City
680 M. Malvar St. Malate, Manila
71 Mt. Mayon St., Singson Village Subangdaku, Mandaue City
98-C Padaba Street
Brgy 1 Zone 13 Aquino
```

The output should be:

```
71 Mt. Mayon St., Singson Village Subangdaku, Mandaue City
98-C Padaba Street
Brgy 1 Zone 13 Aquino
```

Comment: Please tag the *actual* database you are using. MySql <> SQL Server.

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the correction. I'm using SQL server. I'm really new to SQL so please bear with me.

Comment: @DaleK here is my code sample

SELECT SUBSTRING(Address, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Address), LEN(Address))
FROM Student
WHERE Address LIKE '%[0-9]%'

I'm stuck at selecting the address with only 2digit numbers. I have 9 entries on my data and 8 of them were showing on the output which doesn't have a number.

Comment: [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One set-based approach you could try is to split the characters of each address into rows and count the numerical values, then filter using an aggregate. A slight complication is where you have separate single digit numbers, which can be filtered out using `patindex`.

To split the string requires use of a *numbers / tally* table - I'm using a CTE just for a working example, a permanent table would be preferable and has many uses.

```
with t as (select top (60) Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.sysmessages)

select Address
from Tablename cross apply t
where t.n <= Len(address) and t.n-1 !=patindex('% [0-9] %',address)
group by address
having Sum(case when Ascii(Substring(address,t.n,1)) between 48 and 57 then 1 else 0 end) = 2
```

See [example DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=445ce7be80703b1125c2e5fd35c8b64e)

Another possible solution could be with just `patindex` although more sample data would really be required.

For the sample data given the following returns the expected result:

```
select * 
from t
where patindex('[0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',address)>0 
  or patindex('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',address)>0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll study it first because I am basically new to SQL but I really want to learn.

Comment: the other solution is the right one for me. Thank you for your patience in answering my questions. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Second solution does not find an address that has 2 digits at end of it.

Comment: Hello! I've tried the second solution and it gives me the right answer @sddk

Comment: Do you have an address that has 2 digits at end of it?

Comment: @sddk None, all addresses that has a 2 digit number is either at the first or in between of other string.

Comment: If you have digits on the end you can just add `or patindex('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9]',address)>0` - as I mentioned the test data should cover all scenarios. What if you have a 2 digit number and a 3 digit number...?

Answer (score 0):

Note:   Your third example has `1`, so clearly "2 digits" really means "1 or two digits".

I would recommend using `like`.  In SQL Server, you can use:

```
where address like '%[0-9][0-9]%' and
      address not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

The first condition checks that there are two digits in a row.  The second condition checks that there are never three digits in a row.

If you don't actually need two digits, then the second condition is sufficient:

```
where address not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this also gives the same output from my data, when there is a scenario that the data has both 2 digit number and a 3 digit number it won't show in the output. My problem is just to show a string that contains 2 digit number, whether it has a 2nd number that contains 3 or more digits.